# How to fix "RangeError: Invalid Websocket frame: invalid payload length 126" In NestJS GraphQL Subscription (graphql-ws)

Tags: graphql, nestjs

In NestJS GraphQL Subscription (graphql-ws),
The error is occurring for an unknown reason.

"RangeError: Invalid Websocket frame: invalid payload length 126"
We also do not know the conditions under which the error occurred.

When this error appears, it shuts down the server, which is very fatal.

I think, problem point is graphql-ws or nestjs8 (graphql)
But in downgrade nestjs 7, It works fine.

minimum reproduction link : https://github.com/maemenaver/nestjs-graphql-ws-issue

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I currently have the same issue

Comment: @Nicolas See here, https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/discussions/243